# Solve for x given an interpolation function, y

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

Given a list of data,

```
lst={{x1,y2},{x2,y2},...,{xn,yn}}
```

and the interpolation function fun,

```
y=Interpolation[lst]
```

which can be plotted as,

```
Plot[y[x],{x,x1,xn}]
```

as usual. I've tried to apply `Solve` in order to obtain x given `y=y0` as

```
Solve[y[x]==y0,x]
```

and get

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may  not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

Comment: Try `InverseFunction[y]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. You mean  `InverseFunction[y][y0] ` , it does not work. I know it is a bit trivial, but maybe has to do with the fact it is an interpolation.

Comment: That means your interpolating function is not one-to-one; that is only valid for one-to-one functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can reverse the value of `{x,y}` to `{y,x}`, and then interpolate them.

Note:In this case, the value of $y$ cannot be *duplicate*

```
lst=
 {{3.61648, 5.64818}, {7.53428, 4.52803}, {4.21088, 2.35117}, 
  {4.48224,1.08325}, {4.63735, 5.5877}, {2.24299, 3.10376}}

x = Interpolation[Reverse /@ data];
x[3.]
```

> ```
>  2.44086
> ```

**Method 2**

If the the values of $y$ are be *duplicate*, you should interpolate in two directions.

For instance, using the following method

> [image]

```
Options[interpolateCurve] = 
 Join[Options[ParametricPlot3D], Options[Interpolation]];

interpolateCurve[pts : {{_, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Module[{order, x, y, s, func1, func2},
   order = OptionValue[InterpolationOrder];
   x = pts[[All, 1]];
   y = pts[[All, 2]];
   (*calculate the accumulative chord length*)
   s =
    FoldList[
     Plus, 0, EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]];
   (*interpolation points with spline-method in two directions*)
   {func1, func2} =
    Interpolation[
     Thread@{s, #}, InterpolationOrder -> order, Method -> "Spline"] & /@ {x, y};
    (*visualize the curve*)
   ParametricPlot[{func1[t], func2[t]}, {t, 0, Last[s]},
    Evaluate@
     (Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]]), 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[pts]}]
]
```

Comment: Method 1 worked. Thanks

Comment: @Resanrom, My pleasure, and I will complete the method 2 when I have time. Now I am  busy:-)

Comment: @Resanrom, I have completed the **method 2**

Comment: .Thank you very much, your answers are really useful. I learn a lot.

Comment: @xyz This is probably late, but for method 2, even though you can plot the inverse function, you can't actually extract the data points, that is, for a given `y`, you can obtain all the solutions `x1,x2,x3,...` such that `y==foo[x]`. Is there a work around?

Answer (score 4):

you can try `FindRoot`

```
f = Interpolation[{1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5}];
sol = FindRoot[f[x] == 2.5, {x, 3}]
(*{x -> 2.5641}*)
Plot[{f[x], 2.5}, {x, 1, 6}, GridLines -> {{x /. sol}, None}]
```

[image]